# What really happened to Dr John Woods?

Tags: character, extant

Is Dr John Woods in *Extant* really dead? We see him in a seemingly inescapable situation and then, 6 months later, we hear someone claiming that he died. Given that season 2 is still running, do we have an out of universe confirmation of whether or not John actually died, or whether he is going to turn up in another 6 months having been beamed to safety by aliens or something?

I know that the supposedly correct thing to do is to wait and see as the series unfolds, but I'm not sure it's worth the invested attention. I'm definitely far more engaged with the humanichs "Pinocchio 2.0" thread than with the alien ghost story thread. I don't really want to sink 13 hours into a show I'm not really enjoying, just so that I'm up to speed on the off-chance that it picks up again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [spoilers for the 2nd season](http://www.latinpost.com/articles/57084/20150602/extant-season-2-spoilers-goran-visnjic-leaves-series.htm):

> Goran Visnjic, the 42-year-old Croatian actor who plays Dr. John Woods, Molly Woods' (Berry) robotics engineering husband, will be leaving the series. But before he makes his full exit, according to Entertainment Weekly’s Natalie Abrams, he will make an appearance at the start of Season 2.

Yes he's dead. But will make an appearance in season 2.

Answer (score 0):

The 42-year-old Croatian actor [Goran Visnjic](http://www.latimes.com/business/realestate/hot-property/la-fi-hotprop-goran-visnjic-20150916-story.html) who plays Dr. John Woods made an appearance at the start of Season 2 before he made his full exit. Goran Visnjic was also back for the premiere.